# Get List of manualy selected features on MXD and run script on selected features :

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, select

Using arcgis 10.3, I trying to write code that when i do selection on layer manualy on MXD (not in the script) and run the script, the script need to run just on the selected features.
I have tried -

```
layer = "Source Layer Path"
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
selected = desc.name
print (selected)
```

but it returns an empty list, is there a way to this in python?

I have tried this :

```
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(Mxd)[0]
Layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(Mxd, "", dataFrame)[0]
desc = arcpy.Describe(Layers)
selected = desc.Fidset
print ("selected = "+ str(selected))
```

Still same result

Comment: By "selection on layer" do you mean select features or the actual layer in the table of contents?

Comment: I mean select the feature in the layer in MXD not the actual layer in the table of contents

Comment: Do you have a layer in your MXD called "Source Layer Path"?  or is this referring to a path to a feature class?

Comment: "Source Layer Path", is the Path for layer in MXD,

Answer (score 2):

Your `layer` needs to refer to the layer in your MXD, not the path to the feature class.

```
layer = "Layer In MXD"
desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
selected = desc.FIDSet
print (selected)
```

`desc.Fidset` will return the ObjectIDs of the selected features

---

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", dataFrame)[0]

for layer in layers:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer) 
    selected = desc.FIDSet 
    print ("selected = "+ str(selected))
```

Comment: I have tried this :

dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(Mxd)[0]

Layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(Mxd, "", dataFrame)[0]

desc = arcpy.Describe(Layers)


selected = desc.Fidset

print ("selected = "+ str(selected))


Still same result

Comment: that's because Layers is a list of layers.  You need to loop through your layers.  I'll update my answer

Comment: When i loop through List layers i got error:

AttributeError: LayerObject: Get attribute layers does not exist

Answer (score -1):

I find the answer :
Need to do MakeFeatureLayer_management

```
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(Mxd)[0]
Layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(Mxd, "", dataFrame)[0]
for layer in dataFrame:
        Layers=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(Mxd, "", dataFrame)[0]
        if Layers.name=="Signs":
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layer,"Signs_Shape_layer")
            desc = arcpy.Describe("Signs_Shape_layer")
            FID_selected = desc.FIDSet
            selected = FID_selected.split("; ")
            print (selected)
            break
```